# Error: Could not find a match for std::multimap

Tags: c++, cc

I am trying to compile a C++ application on SUN server using the compiler Sun C++ 5.9 SunOS_sparc Patch 124863-01.I am getting the below error while compiling

```
 Error: Could not find a match for std::multimap<std::string, OutputNamespace::FUPInfo, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, OutputNamespace::FUPInfo>>>::insert(std::pair<std::string, OutputNamespace::FUPInfo>) needed in operator<<(std::ostream &, InvoiceOutput&).
```

Is this a compiler related issue?do you have any idea how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: so that mean that this code will not be compiled ? there any workaround to avoid this bug ? or some patch maybe?
I read on some internet that this can be avoided using the flag -library=stlport4 but actually I dont know which impact this will have on the application, can you advise me regarding this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a defect in the Sun compiler to maintain backwards ABI compatibility with its original standard library (which lacks very many features). It wants the `insert` pair to be the internal value type of the map (with `const`) added to the key, rather than the *actual* key type you've requested in the multimap declaration. For example the following compiles:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::multimap<std::string, int> mapperizer;

    mapperizer.insert(std::pair<const std::string, int>(std::string("Foo"), 42));
}
```

Also, the original version will compile successfully with stlport4 (command line argument `-library=stlport4`).